# Haskell replace element in list

Tags: haskell, built-in

Is there any built-in function to replace an element at a given index in haskell?

Example:

`replaceAtIndex(2,"foo",["bar","bar","bar"])`

Should give:

```
["bar", "bar", "foo"]
```

I know i could make my own function, but it just seems it should be built-in.

Answer (score 38):

If you need to update elements at a specific index, lists aren't the most efficient data structure for that. You might want to consider using `Seq` from [`Data.Sequence`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.6.3/docs/Data-Sequence.html) instead, in which case the function you're looking for is [`update :: Int -> a -> Seq a -> Seq a`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.6.3/docs/Data-Sequence.html#v:update).

```
> import Data.Sequence
> update 2 "foo" $ fromList ["bar", "bar", "bar"]
fromList ["bar","bar","foo"]
```

Comment: This seems to be exactly what i need. Thanks!

Comment: I have done this. Now, how do I change the Seq a to a ?

Comment: @MickaelBergeronNéron you can get `[a]` out of `Seq a` with `Data.Foldable.foldr (:) []`. If you have an `f :: a -> a -> a` operation, you can call `Data.Foldable.foldr f` with some initial element (like 0), to get the combined `a` value.

Comment: @MickaelBergeronNéron we also get `[a]` out of `Seq a` with `Data.Foldable.foldMap (:[])` (or with other Monoids, like e.g. `Data.Foldable.foldMap Sum` for numbers, etc.).

Answer (score 15):

As far as I know (and can find) it does not exist by default. However, there exists `splitAt` in `Data.List` so:

```
replaceAtIndex n item ls = a ++ (item:b) where (a, (_:b)) = splitAt n ls
```

This is O(N) though. If you find yourself doing this a lot, look at another datatype such as array.

Comment: It's not `O(n)` in general but `O(i)`, where `i` is the split index (because only the prefix needs to be copied). If that index is constant, the operation is `O(1)`.

Comment: Always a good idea to include a type signature: `replaceAtIndex :: Int -> a -> [a] -> [a]`

Answer (score 10):

There is actual arrays, but lists are really singly linked lists and the notion of replacing an element is not quite as obvious (and accessing an element at a given index may indicate that you shouldn't be using a list, so operations that might encourage it are avoided).

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

```
import Data.List

replaceAtIndex :: Int -> a -> [a] -> [a]    
replaceAtIndex i x xs = take i xs ++ [x] ++ drop (i+1) xs
```

It works as follows:

get the first i items, add the value 'x', add the rest of i+1 items