# How to set value in nth element in a Haskell list?

Tags: list, haskell

I know that `xs !! n` gives me nth element in a list, but I don't know how to edit nth element in that list. Can you tell me how can I edit nth element in a list or give a hint at least?

For example how can I make the second element `'a'` an `'e'` in this: `['s','t','a','c','k']`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace individual list elements in Haskell?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5852722/replace-individual-list-elements-in-haskell)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Because Haskell is a functional language, you cannot 'edit' elements in lists, because everything is immutable. Instead, you can create a new list with something like:

```
take n xs ++ [newElement] ++ drop (n + 1) xs
```

However, it is not recommended in Haskell. For some more information you can see this post: [Haskell replace element in list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10133361/haskell-replace-element-in-list)

Comment: I'm wondering if `Hasekll` is smart enough not to build a new entire vector ?  like in `clojure` it will keep rest of the elements of list `unchanged`/`uncopied`

Answer (score 21):

### Changing the nth element

A common operation in many languages is to assign to an indexed position in an array.  In python you might:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> a[3] = 9
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 9, 5]
```

The 
[lens](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens) package gives this functionality with the `(.~)` operator.  Though unlike in python the original list is not mutated, rather a new list is returned.

```
> let a = [1,2,3,4,5]
> a & element 3 .~ 9
[1,2,3,9,5]
> a
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

`element 3 .~ 9` is just a function and the `(&)` operator, part of the 
[lens](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens) package, is just reverse function application.  Here it is with more common function application.

```
> (element 3 .~ 9) [1,2,3,4,5]
[1,2,3,9,5]
```

Assignment again works perfectly fine with arbitrary nesting of `Traversable`s.

```
> [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]] & element 0 . element 1 .~ 9
[[1,9,3],[4,5,6]]
```

or

```
> set (element 3) 9 [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

Or if you want to effect multiple elements you can use:

```
> over (elements (>3)) (const 99) [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
> [1,2,3,4,99,99,99]
```

### Working with types other then lists

This is not just limited to lists however, it will work with any datatype that is an instance of the [Traversable](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.1.2/docs/Control-Lens-Traversal.html#t%3aTraversable) typeclass.

Take for example the same technique works on [trees](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.5.1/docs/Data-Tree.html) form the standard 
[containers](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers) package.

```
 > import Data.Tree
 > :{
 let
  tree = Node 1 [
       Node 2 [Node 4[], Node 5 []]
     , Node 3 [Node 6 [], Node 7 []]
     ]
 :}
> putStrLn . drawTree . fmap show $ tree
1
|
+- 2
|  |
|  +- 4
|  |
|  `- 5
|
`- 3
   |
   +- 6
   |
   `- 7
> putStrLn . drawTree . fmap show $ tree & element 1 .~ 99
1
|
+- 99
|  |
|  +- 4
|  |
|  `- 5
|
`- 3
   |
   +- 6
   |
   `- 7
> putStrLn . drawTree . fmap show $ tree & element 3 .~ 99
1
|
+- 2
|  |
|  +- 4
|  |
|  `- 99
|
`- 3
   |
   +- 6
   |
   `- 7
> putStrLn . drawTree . fmap show $ over (elements (>3)) (const 99) tree
1
|
+- 2
|  |
|  +- 4
|  |
|  `- 5
|
`- 99
   |
   +- 99
   |
   `- 99
```

Comment: It's great to introduce the lens package and explain it's generality but I think a beginner will learn more from the 2 simpler solutions following.

Answer (score 10):

You can't edit the nth element of a list, values are immutable. You have to create a new list. But due to the immutability, it can share the part after the changed element with the original list.

So if you want to apply a transformation to the nth element of a list (and have the parts before and after identical), you have three parts

- the front of the list before the element in question, say `front`
- the element in question, say `element`
- the back of the list after the element in question, say `back`.

Then you'd assemble the parts

```
front ++ transform element : back
```

so it remains to get a hold on the interesting parts in a nice way.

```
splitAt :: Int -> [a] -> ([a],[a])
```

does that, `splitAt idx list` gives back the first part of the list, before the index `idx` as the first component of the pair, and the rest as the second, so

```
changeNthElement :: Int -> (a -> a) -> [a] -> [a]
changeNthElement idx transform list
    | idx < 0   = list
    | otherwise = case spliAt idx list of
                    (front, element:back) -> front ++ transform element : back
                    _ -> list    -- if the list doesn't have an element at index idx
```

(Note: I have started counting elements at 0, if you want to start counting at 1, you need to adjust and use `idx-1`.)

Comment: Thank you very much for such a nice and helpful answer. Can you tell me if **transform list** in the line **changeNthElement idx transform list** is only one  input?

Comment: `transform` is the function you use to obtain the new element from the old. I have been more general than just replacing an element with a given one, so you could do for example `changeNthElement 3 (*2) list` to double the element at index 3.

Answer (score 5):

I' surprised the following method was not yet mentioned, so I will add it for further reference:

```
replace index elem = map (\(index', elem') -> if index' == index then elem else elem') . zip [0..]

> replace 2 'e' "stack"
"steck"
```

It handle the casse of out of range index.

```
> replace (-1) 'z' "abc"
"abc"
> replace 0 'z' "abc"
"zbc"
> replace 2 'z' "abc"
"abz"
> replace 3 'z' "abc"
"abc"
```

It is not slower than the splitAt method ( O(2N) ).

Comment: It is slower than the splitAt method and it will use more memory. Suppose  the length of the string is n. Your function will process all n elements while split at will only process index elements. Also your function will create n new list elements while splitAt creates index new list elements. i.e. your function is O(n) while split at is O(index). n could be much larger than index.

Answer (score 1):

There is also the possibility of writing **a simple recursive solution**.

The basic idea is that, in order to substitute element #5 in a list, you just have to substitute element #4 in the *tail* of that list.

Using the notations from the answer of @DanielFisher, this gives the following code:

```
changeNthElement :: Int -> (a -> a) -> [a] -> [a]
changeNthElement n fn   []    =  []   -- nothing to change
changeNthElement n fn (x:xs)
    |  (n < 0)    =  x:xs             -- no change for a negative index
    |  (n == 0)   =  (fn x) : xs                          -- easy case
    |  otherwise  =  x : (changeNthElement (n-1) fn xs)   -- recursion
```

If the new value does not depend on the old one, one can specialize the above function:

```
setNthElement :: Int -> a  -> [a] -> [a]
setNthElement n v xs = changeNthElement n (const v) xs
```

**Testing:**

```
$ ghci
 GHCi, version 8.8.4: https://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
 ...
 λ> 
 λ> :load q15530511.hs
 [1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( q15530511.hs, interpreted )
 Ok, one module loaded.
 λ> 
 λ> xs = replicate 10 7
 λ> 
 λ> xs
 [7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7]
 λ> 
 λ> changeNthElement  3 (+2) xs
 [7,7,7,9,7,7,7,7,7,7]
 λ> 
 λ> setNthElement 2 42 xs
 [7,7,42,7,7,7,7,7,7,7]
 λ>
```