# Sum all elements with same snd of a list Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, recursion

I'm trying to do a polynomial calculator in Haskell and I'm having some problems with the multiplication. The polynomials are introduced as a list of coefficients where the first term corresponds to x^0, the second one corresponds to x^1 and so on.

For the multiplication I have a list of tuples which indicate, on the first element, the coefficient they belong to and, on the second element, they show the corresponding coefficient:

```
[(0,0),(0,-1),(0,-2),(0,-3),(0,-4),(0,1),(1,0),(2,-1),(3,-2),(4,-3),(0,2),(2,1),(4,0)
```

(This is done to keep reference to each item multiplied and the coefficient it belongs to)

Since it's one of my first steps into functional programming I'm having some trouble on making a list where the first element is the sum of all the second elements from the tuples on the list shown above with 0 as its first element, the second term should be the sum of all second elemts from the tuples in the list shown above with 1 as its first element, and so on.

I tried with Data.Sequence update as pointed in the first answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10133361/haskell-replace-element-in-list)  but it doesn't seems to 'update' an already created Data.Sequence, It returns a new one each time.

Is there any way to create a list and update its contents based on index? I'm trying to figure how to solve this problem recursively but I have no idea how to do it so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Haskell. Things are simple and immutable in this world. So you don't update but create a new immutable structure every time.

Comment: I really need to get used to it since I come from Java, Python, C, etc. and this is like a whole new horizon. I've been trying with list comprehension but I can't find a way to do it.

Comment: The first step in learning Haskell is to let go of your concerns about efficiency and copies. Later on, when you understand what is going on, you can pick up the efficiency concerns again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the solution,

```
import Data.List
import Data.Function

combine :: [(Int,Int)] -> [Int]
combine = map (sum . map snd) . groupBy ((==) `on` fst) . sort
```

Read the function from right to left to understand what it is doing.

Here is the breakage into smaller parts to understand it

```
*Main> sort [(0,0),(0,-1),(0,-2),(0,-3),(0,-4),(0,1),(1,0),(2,-1),(3,-2),(4,-3),(0,2),(2,1),(4,0)]
[(0,-4),(0,-3),(0,-2),(0,-1),(0,0),(0,1),(0,2),(1,0),(2,-1),(2,1),(3,-2),(4,-3),(4,0)]
```

This sorts the list, so all pairs with same first element are together. After this you can also use a `fold`.

```
*Main> groupBy ((==) `on` fst) . sort $ [(0,0),(0,-1),(0,-2),(0,-3),(0,-4),(0,1),(1,0),(2,-1),(3,-2),(4,-3),(0,2),(2,1),(4,0)]
[[(0,-4),(0,-3),(0,-2),(0,-1),(0,0),(0,1),(0,2)],[(1,0)],[(2,-1),(2,1)],[(3,-2)],[(4,-3),(4,0)]]
```

This combines all the pairs with same first element.

```
*Main> combine [(0,0),(0,-1),(0,-2),(0,-3),(0,-4),(0,1),(1,0),(2,-1),(3,-2),(4,-3),(0,2),(2,1),(4,0)]
[-7,0,0,-2,-3]
```

Now we just need to calculate the sum of the second element in the list of lists.

Comment: Just what I was looking for! Thanks for your help, I have to get used to build a new structure every time.

Comment: I took to long to answer because I was trying to understand the code and I think I got to understand it but your explanation makes it better. Once again Thank you!

Comment: @Jose_Sunstrider Its not like the run time system actually builds a new structure everytime. Because of immutability, most of the things are shared. Also compiler has opportunity to fuse the above operations into a tight loop so that the intermediate structure are even not created.